# Bedeutungswandel des Wortes "gemein"

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Angeregt durch die [Frage nach dem Präfix "hund(s)-"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/whats-so-bad-about-dogs/3970) und der akzeptierten Antwort, stellte sich mir die Frage, wann das Wort "gemein" einen Bedeutungswandelt von "gewöhnlich, alltäglich" hin zu "hinterhältig" durchgemacht hat.

Hiermit sind natürlich nicht biologische Bezeichnungen wie "gemeine Stubenfliege" et al. gemeint.

Comment: Randbemerkung: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pejoration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der [Kluge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_deutschen_Sprache) (24. Aufl., 2002) sagt:

> **gemein** (...) (8. Jh.), mittelhochdeutsch *gemein(e)*, althochdeutsch *gimeini*, altsächsisch *gimEni*. Aus germanisch
>   *ga-maini*, "*allgemein*", auch in gotisch *gamains*, altenglisch *gemäne*, altfranzösisch *mEne*. Genau gleich gebildet ist lateinisch *commUnis* gleicher Bedeutung (wohl zu lateinisch *mUnus* "*Verrichtung, Aufgabe*"). Zugrunde liegt ein (indogermanisch)
>   *moino-* "*Wechsel, Tausch*" (*Meineid*); Ausgangsbedeutung ist also "*worin man sich abwechselt, was einem im Wechsel zukommt*". Die
>   Bedeutungsverschlechterung (die bei Wörtern dieser Sphäre häufig ist)
>   ist erst neuhochdeutsch. Die Ausgangsbedeutung ist erhalten in dem
>   Abstraktum *Gemeinschaft*, die neue Bedeutung speziell in
>   *Gemeinheit*.  Ebenso neuniederländisch *gemeen*, neuenglisch *mean*. Siehe auch *Gemeinde*, *Allmende*, *handgemein*, *Meineid* und zum
>   lateinischen Wort *immun*, *Kommune*.

"Neuhochdeutsch" heißt also (grob!) ab dem 17. Jahrhundert.

Interessant auch der Wandel von niederträchtig:

> **niederträchtig** (...) (15. Jh.) Zuerst als *nidertrechtic* "*herablassend*" zu mittelhochdeutsch *sich tragen* "*sich benehmen*"
>   (also "*sich nach unten benehmend*"). Im 16. Jh. dazu auch
>   *hochträchtig* "*hochfahrend*". Im 18. Jh. verschlechtert sich die Bedeutung zu "*sittlich gemein*", wozu dann als Rückbildung das
>   Substantiv *Niedertracht*.

Betont kein Wandel auch bei *allgemein*:

> **allgemein** (...) (12. Jh.) Verstärkung von *gemein* in dessen ursprünglicher Bedeutung durch *all*. Bei der
>   Bedeutungsverschlechterung des Grundworts bleibt die alte Bedeutung
>   bei *allgemein*.

Ein paar Beispiele aus dem Neuhochdeutschen wären jetzt noch interessant ...

Answer (score 6):

Im [Deutschen Etymologischen Wörterbuch](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/der/DERG.pdf) heißt es auf Seite 150

> **gemein**, Adj., gemein, öffentlich, einfach (15. Jh.), nicht wertvoll, niederträchtig (19. Jh.)

Answer (score 3):

Was außerdem total interessant ist, ist nicht nur die Feststellung, dass das Wort "gemein" eine immer negativere Bedeutung erhielt, sondern auch die nahezu identische, parallele Entwicklung dieses Wortes im Englischen und Russischen!

Denn "gemein" kommt ja vom indogermanischen "Abwechseln, Tauschen", wird dann im Sinne von "übereinstimmend, bei Mehreren zutreffend" benutzt und schließlich zu "niederträchtig, fies" usw.

Im Englischen passierte das Gleiche mit dem Wort "common", das aus dem Lateinischen kommt: Im Lateinischen bedeutet es ebenfalls "gemeinsam" und wird ebenfalls aus dem Indogermanischen abgeleitet: ko-(zusammen)-moini.
Das Wort "common" wird später auch im Sinn von "vulgär" (übrigens von lat. vulgata "im Volk verbreitet"!) und "ordinär", "minderwertig" verwendet.

Ok, diese beiden Srachen haben somit eine gemeinsame Grundlage – die indogermansiche Sprache (auch das genannte gemein/(sam) -> mean - u. a. als durchschnittlich).
Aber jetzt kommt's: im Russischen heißt "общее" - "allen Gemeinsames", gleichzeitig heißt "общение" - Kommunikation, Austausch!! (Somit ebenfalls selbe Grundlage). Und außerdem hat "общее" eine zweite Bedeutung: etwas Austauschbares also Wertloses, Durchschnittliches (übrigens hier auch eine Parallele – Austausch als Kommunikation, aber Austauschbarkeit als Minderwertigkeit).

Comment: Übrigens hat auch das englische "mean" neben der Bedeutung "durchschnittlich" auch die Bedeutung "fies".