# Etymologie von "gemein"

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bedeutungswandel des Wortes “gemein”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/bedeutungswandel-des-wortes-gemein)

Das Wort "gemein" kommt in verschiedenen Zusammenhängen vor, wie z. B.

- das *gemeine* Volk (in der Bedeutung des *einfachen* Volkes)
- Dieser Mensch ist *gemein* (in Sinne von er ist *bösartig* oder *hinterhältig*)

Wird hier das gleiche Wort verwendet oder gibt es zwei verschiedene Wortstämme. Wie ist die Etymologie des Wortes "gemein"?

Die Frage [Bedeutungswandel des Wortes gemein](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/bedeutungswandel-des-wortes-gemein) hilft hier nicht weiter.

Comment: FWIW, the same thing happens in English with "mean" (which can be taken either as "average", or as "base, vile, evil"), and even with the Latin-derived "community" and "common" (which can be used in the sense of "ordinary, vulgar, lowborn").  A historical connection between the two meanings seems quite plausible to me.

Comment: Here's one way to look at it: one would expect that patricians and plebeians will attach rather different connotations to words associated with "the common people": derogatory ones for the former (e.g. "mean"=lowly,nasty; "common"=ordinary,vulgar;), and neutral/positive ones for the latter ("mean"=average,normal; "common"=ours, as in "commonwealth", "community", "common good", "common decency", etc.)  The language retains all these echoes, even when they come from opposing camps.

Comment: Auch wenn die besteheden Antworten vielleicht nicht genau das sagen, was Du erwartest, sollten wir es vermeiden eine identische Frage erneut zu stellen. Man könnte beispielweise die alte Frage pushen oder mit einem Bounty versehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/bedeutungswandel-des-wortes-gemein) zur Frage zum Bedeutungswandel enthält tatsächlich implizit die Antwort zu dieser Frage:

> Die Bedeutungsverschlechterung (die bei Wörtern dieser Sphäre häufig
> ist) ist erst neuhochdeutsch. Die Ausgangsbedeutung ist erhalten in
> dem Abstraktum Gemeinschaft, die neue Bedeutung speziell in
> Gemeinheit.

Ähnlich im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gemein):

> **Herkunft**
>
> mittelhochdeutsch gemein(e), althochdeutsch gimeini, ursprünglich =
> mehreren abwechselnd zukommend; der abwertende Nebensinn stammt aus
> der Vorstellung, dass das, was vielen gemeinsam ist, nicht wertvoll
> sein kann

Beide Quellen (Kluge und Duden) erwähnen zwar nicht explizit, dass es sich um ein und dasselbe Wort und damit auch um denselben Wortstamm handelt, da aber jeweils die Rede von „Bedeutungsverschlechterung“ bzw. „Nebenbedeutung“ ist, ist die Implikation m. E. ziemlich klar.